# How to bind output value into model

Tags: xml, output, orbeon, xforms

I've got this binding to the output field:

```
 <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
        <xf:bind id="Pokoj-bind" ref="dok:Pokoj" name="Pokoj" />
    </xf:bind>
     <xh:body>
    <xh:td>
      <xf:output id="Pokoj-control" value="concat('Pokój ',xxf:repeat-position())"
                                               bind="Pokoj-bind">
         <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Pokoj/label"/>
         <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Pokoj/hint"/>
         <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
      </xf:output>
    </xh:td>
   </xh:body>
```

but value of the output it's not saved to the model I would be grateful for any kind of help how to bind value of this to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike an `xf:input` that can also "write" a value to its bound node, say when users change the value in the input field, an `xf:output` just reads a value from its bound node, or shows a value coming from the `value="..."` attribute, as you did here. But the fact that you have a `bind="..."` on the `xf:output` in addition to the `value="..."` doesn't get the `xf:output` to write that value into the bound node.

Typically, you would achieve this by moving expression you now have on the `xf:output value="..."` to an `xf:bind calculate="..."`. In your case, you can't do *exactly* that, as the `xxf:repeat-position()` won't work in the model. So you'll most likely need to write something like `calculate="concat('Pokój ',count(preceding-sibling::dok:Pokoj))"`.

Comment: Thank you but I have just one more question, ok now the value of field is in the model but all fields got value "Pokój 0" I would be kindly grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Right, my bad: since you have a repeat, the `dok:Pokoj` is inside an element that is repeated. Normally, this is the name of the grid. You can find what the name is by checking the source of the form. Assuming it is `container`, then the expression will be `../count(preceding-sibling::container))`.